# How do I show a chart within a container?

Tags: charts, flutter

I am fairly new to flutter and oop. So please bear with me.

I try to show a chart, made with charts_flutter library, within a Container widget (see code line 10). I tried to call CustomRoundedBar object there, but this gives me a type error, telling me that the type 'Type' can not be loaded where a type 'Widget' is expected.

What do I have to do, that I can show a chart within a container? or any other widget?

Every help is appreciated.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;

class Insights extends StatelessWidget {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      //child: Text('This is text in a Container'),
    );
  }
}




class CustomRoundedBars extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<charts.Series> seriesList;
  final bool animate;

  CustomRoundedBars(this.seriesList, {this.animate});

  /// Creates a [BarChart] with custom rounded bars.
  factory CustomRoundedBars.withSampleData() {
    return new CustomRoundedBars(
      _createSampleData(),
      // Disable animations for image tests.
      animate: false,
    );
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new charts.BarChart(
      seriesList,
      animate: animate,
      defaultRenderer: new charts.BarRendererConfig(
        // By default, bar renderer will draw rounded bars with a constant
        // radius of 100.
        // To not have any rounded corners, use [NoCornerStrategy]
        // To change the radius of the bars, use [ConstCornerStrategy]
          cornerStrategy: const charts.ConstCornerStrategy(30)),
    );
  }

  /// Create one series with sample hard coded data.
  static List<charts.Series<OrdinalSales, String>> _createSampleData() {
    final data = [
      new OrdinalSales('2014', 5),
      new OrdinalSales('2015', 25),
      new OrdinalSales('2016', 100),
      new OrdinalSales('2017', 75),
    ];

    return [
      new charts.Series<OrdinalSales, String>(
        id: 'Sales',
        colorFn: (_, __) => charts.MaterialPalette.blue.shadeDefault,
        domainFn: (OrdinalSales sales, _) => sales.year,
        measureFn: (OrdinalSales sales, _) => sales.sales,
        data: data,
      )
    ];
  }
}

/// Sample ordinal data type.
class OrdinalSales {
  final String year;
  final int sales;

  OrdinalSales(this.year, this.sales);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construct a chart and pass that as the `child` parameter to the constructor of `Container`.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: CustomRoundedBars.withSampleData(),
    );
  }
```